# btrfs partition not detected

Tags: btrfs

I have some distros installed on a BTRFS partitions under different subvolumes ( for distro-hopping, separate ext4 boot). This btrfs partition is now not getting detected on boot, while I can access them after I boot to another distro living in another ext4 partition.

I believe its because I did a `tune2fs` on this BTRFS partition mistakenly assuming its an `ext4` so as to disable journalling.

Using `testdisk`, it wrongly identified the partition as ext4. But after an incomplete *deeper* search, it showed up as btrfs correctly. I think this is problem - the partition getting identified as ext4 on a *quick breeze*. But the boot message is actually saying `dev/sda9` not found.

One solution I *should* try is to fire up `fdisk` and change the type to BTRFS, but I doubt if I will loose the data.

Is this operation safe? 
How can I fix the partition for it to get detected as BTRFS at boot?